# How to check if a value exist before adding with python?

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I want to write a new text line to a file in python3 in combination with streamlet. So I have this code to do the check but even when the text exists it still writes it to the file. Any idea what I did wrong? Here is a part of the code.

```
if selected == "Setup":
    st.subheader('Trainers')
    with st.form("Add trainer", clear_on_submit=True):
        Add_trainer = st.text_input('Enter additional trainer:')
        
        submitted = st.form_submit_button('Add trainer')
        if submitted:
            if Add_trainer:
                add_trainer_to_file('trainers.txt', Add_trainer)
            else:
                st.warning("Please enter a trainer name first!")
```

And here is the function that handles it.

```
def add_trainer_to_file(file_path, trainer_name):
    trainer_name = trainer_name.strip().title() # make sure the trainer name has proper capitalization
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        # Check if the trainer name is already in the file (case insensitive)
        if trainer_name.lower() + '\n' in [line.strip().lower() for line in lines]:
            st.warning(f"{trainer_name} already exists in the file.")
        else:
            lines.append(trainer_name + '\n') # add the trainer name to the list
            with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
                f.writelines(lines) # write the updated list to the file
                st.success(f"{trainer_name} added to the file.")
```

I did a lot of things like searching here and also on other sources, but when I tried I can't find any suitable solution.

Comment: You're stripping lines you read from the file, which removes newlines. But then you're adding a newline to the element before comparing it against the list. You could try printing the needle and haystack to see what's going on here.

Comment: I have tried every possible solution, even with stripping, and it did not work. Will look again this evening when I am home.

Answer (score 1):

In your `add_trainer_to_file` function, change:

```py
if trainer_name.lower() + '\n' in [line.strip().lower() for line in lines]:
```

To

```py
if trainer_name.lower() in [line.strip().lower() for line in lines]:
```

**Reason why the code still writes existing trainer:** 
Your list comprehension in the if statement `[line.strip().lower() for line in lines]` changes the file content to `eg;`

```
trainer1
trainer2
```

Lets say user entered `Trainer1`:
This part of the code `trainer_name.lower() + '\n'` adds a new line to the user input so it becomes like the below snippet. Note the empty line at the bottom of the user input

```
trainer1
```

before checking. So at that point, `trainer1` in the file:

```
trainer1
```

is no longer the same as the user input due to `+ '\n'` and that makes the `else` statement to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`any` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(trainer_name.lower() == line.strip().lower() for line in lines):
    # ...
```